# macOS Terminal Command to Disable Desktop Widgets?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, sonoma

Looking to find a way to use a terminal command to disable/enable desktop widgets in macOS Sonoma. The closest I have been able to find so far is a [script](https://www.macsparky.com/blog/2023/10/applescript-to-toggle-desktop-widgets/) that does this. However, I would like to do this from terminal, or from another app (such as BetterTouchTool) without running the script if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: So run the script from the terminal, or attach a keystroke to it, or have BetterTouchTool run it.

Comment: The script requires that it open system preferences and inserts mouse clicks. As a result, it’s unreliable and slow. Ideally, there’d be a more direct path.